# RequireJS: synchronous requrire text content

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using require for loading html templates, and i want to load these by the synchronous way, for example:

```
var template_a = require(["text!template/a.html"], function(template) { return template; });
var template_b = require(["text!template/b.html"], function(template) { return template; });
var template_c = require(["text!template/c.html"], function(template) { return template; });

$("body").append(template_a);
$("body").append(template_b);
$("body").append(template_c);
```

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this? What would be the potential benefits?

Answer (score 3):

RequireJS is async in its very nature. The only way to overcome it is to do something like this

```
templates = [];

function append_template(template, templates)
{
    templates.push(template);

    if(templates.length == 3)
    {
        for(var i in templates)
            $("body").append(templates[i]);
    }
}

require(["text!template/a.html"], function(template) {
    append_template(template, templates);
});
require(["text!template/b.html"], function(template) {
    append_template(template, templates);
});
require(["text!template/c.html"], function(template) {
    append_template(template, templates);
});
```

Comment: But then it's not different from requiring all templates in a single "template appender" module (but more complicated).

Comment: @kryger definitely:) But 'what for?' is different question.